# How do I get the body of a web request that returned 400 Bad Request from Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: rest, powershell

When I run the following statement

```
Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.mysite.com/the/endpoint" `
    -Body (ConvertTo-Json $data) `
    -ContentType "application/json" `
    -Headers $DefaultHttpHeaders `
    -Method Post
```

the endpoint returns `400 Bad Request`, which causes PowerShell to show the following not-so-helpful message:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest "https://api.mysite.com/the/endpoint" -Body  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

How do I get the body of the response, which might tell me what was wrong with the request I sent?

Comment: @LutzHorn: In this case I know it's my API call that is incorrect. I just don't know exactly *why*.

Comment: Update: `Powershell 7` now has `-SkipHttpErrorCheck`. Details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63392453/322042

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [Invoke-RestMethod](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx) documentation, cmdlet can return different types depending on the content it receives. Assing cmdlet output to a variable (`$resp = Invoke-RestMethod (...)`) and then check if the type is `HtmlWebResponseObject` (`$resp.gettype()`). Then you'll have many properties at your disposal, like BaseResponse, Content and StatusCode.

If `$resp` is some other type (string, psobject and most probably null in this case), it seems that error message `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request` is the response body, only stripped from html (I tested this on some of my methods), maybe even truncated . If you want to extract it, run the cmdlet using common parameter to store the error message: `Invoke-RestMethod (...) -ErrorVariable RespErr`  and you'll have it in `$RespErr` variable.

EDIT:

Ok, I got it and it was pretty obvious :). Invoke-RestMethod throws an error, so lets just catch it:

```
try{$restp=Invoke-RestMethod (...)} catch {$err=$_.Exception}
$err | Get-Member -MemberType Property

  TypeName: System.Net.WebException

    Name           MemberType Definition
    ----           ---------- ----------
    Message        Property   string Message {get;}
    Response       Property   System.Net.WebResponse Response {get;}
    Status         Property   System.Net.WebExceptionStatus Status {get;}
```

Here's all you need, especially in WebResponse object.
I listed 3 properties that catch the eye, there's more. Also if you store `$_` instead of `$_.Exception` there could be some properties PowerShell already extracted for you, but I don't expect nothing more meaningful than in `.Exception.Response`.

Comment: Thanks - using `-ErrorVariable` I was able to get a little more information, but not much. Eventually I resorted to Postman and replicated the request, and got a fuller picture; the body of the response is a JSON object with an `ErrorMessage` (a string) and `Errors` (a list of more specific messages), none of which were shown in the `-ErrorVariable`. Is there no way to get at the response body for failed requests inside Powershell?

Comment: @TomasLycken There is a way after all, please see the edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your persistence! Certainly worth a few points, eh? :)

Comment: The `$_.Exception.Response` is missing the body/content of the response. When I get 400 back, I know the body give me json back. The response even says it's json (`ContentType : application/json`); however the content length is discouraging (`ContentLength : -1`). I'm pretty persistent, but the json is dropped by PowerShell. Tested through v5.0 on Win10 Pro. :(

Comment: In the catch, `$_.TargetObject` will give you the HttpWebRequest object. It might be useful although it won't give you the response (`GetResponse()` will just try again). If you use a web session variable that might also store helpful information.

Answer (score 54):

There is a known issue with PowerShell `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-RestMethod` where the shell eats the response body when the status code is an error (4xx or 5xx). Sounds like the JSON content you are looking for is evaporating in just this manner. You can fetch the response body in your catch block using `$_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()`

```
    try {
    Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.mysite.com/the/endpoint" `
        -Body (ConvertTo-Json $data) `
        -ContentType "application/json" `
        -Headers $DefaultHttpHeaders `
        -Method Post
    }
    catch {
        $streamReader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream())
        $ErrResp = $streamReader.ReadToEnd() | ConvertFrom-Json
        $streamReader.Close()
    }

    $ErrResp
```

Comment: This looks great, but it throws an exception for me: "Method invocation failed because [System.IO.StreamReader] does not contain a method named 'new'."

Comment: What version of .net are you using? I've been using the method above for a a couple of years now.

Comment: I ran `[System.Environment]::Version` in PowerShell, and the result is: Major: 4, Minor: 0, Build: 30319, Revision: 42000

Comment: interesting:

PS C:\> [System.IO.StreamReader]::new
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
System.IO.StreamReader new(System.IO.Stream stream)
System.IO.StreamReader new(System.IO.Stream stream, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks)
System.IO.StreamReader new(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
System.IO.StreamReader new(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Text.Encoding encoding, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks)
System.IO.StreamReader new(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Text.Encoding encoding, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, int bufferSi...

Comment: @Gyromite what about `(Get-ItemProperty ‘HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full’  -Name Release).Release`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me get it working!  That last command outputs 460805 on the Windows 2012 Server VM that I'm trying to run it on.  When I try to display the overloads of "new", it generates no output.  On my local Windows 10 machine, your example works fine, so I gave up on using it on the server. I ended up using this line in the "catch" block instead, just to get the error message to the host:  ``Write-Error ("ERROR occurred: $($_.Exception.Message)`r`n" + "Response body:`r`n$($_.ToString())")``

Comment: I'm glad you found a work around that works for you! Thanks for annotating your experience, hard to believe system.io is broken on a server os. Presently I'm using this on 2012r2, I've used it on XP, Win 7-10 and 2008r2 but never run across your issue.

Comment: use this guys catch block, that's the answer

Comment: Yes this should be marked as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I would like to make a note that, for me, I explicitly had to set the property `BaseStream.Position` to `0` for the `StreamReader` before calling `ReadToEnd()`.

Comment: I second what @srsedate said. I had to put `$streamReader.BaseStream.Position = 0`

Comment: Any chance you could link to some kind of reference and more details for "There is a known issue with PowerShell", if only so that we can tell if it's fixed or not?

Comment: @TimAbell apologies, I've been afk for a few. I have not been able to find my notes on this post, but if I recall I picked up the tip from The Scripting Guy (either in a blog or possibly at TechEd '14 or '16).

Answer (score 12):

$RespErr will have the more details about the BadRequest in my case its

```
$responce = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://localhost:44377/explore/v2/Content -Method Post -Body $PostData -Headers $header -ErrorVariable RespErr;
```

$RespErr;

```
{ "error":{ "code":"","message":"The FavoriteName field is required." } }
```

It looks like it works only in localhost, i tried with my actual server it didn't work.

another way to try is this

```
    try{
$response = ""
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://contentserverint-mhdev.azurewebsites.net/apis/explore/v2/Content?overwrite=true -Method Post -Body $PostData -Headers  $header -ErrorVariable RespErr 
#$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://localhost:44377/explore/v2/Content?overwrite=true -Method Post -Body $PostData -Headers  $header -ErrorVariable RespErr 
Write-Host "Content created with url="$response.value[0] 

}
catch [System.Net.WebException] {   
        $respStream = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
        $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($respStream)
        $respBody = $reader.ReadToEnd() | ConvertFrom-Json
        $respBody;
 }
```

Comment: This one got me the error details I needed to debug the SharePoint REST stuff I'm doing from PowerShell. Thank you.

Comment: why isn't the -ErrorVariable RespError   defined as -ErrorVariable $RespError?   It works but the syntax is confusing

Comment: @GoldenLion Because, like other Powershell cmdlet parameters which create an auxiliary variable like this, you're specifying a string representing the name of the variable that should be created and populated, and not a variable to populate. If you gave it an actual variable it would try to use the value of that variable as the string for the name of the new variable to create.

Answer (score 6):

You can get HTTP response without exceptions regardless if it is 200 or 400:

Powershell 7 introduced `-SkipHttpErrorCheck`

It works for both `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-RestMethod`:

```
PS> $res = Invoke-WebRequest -SkipHttpErrorCheck -Method POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/does-not-exist/oauth2/token
PS> $res    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
StatusCode        : 400                                                                                                                  
StatusDescription : BadRequest                                                                                                           
Content           : {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter:
                     'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: f40877fd-ae34-4b95-a8d4-c7b8ba613801\r\nCorrelation ID: …
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 400 BadRequest
                    Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
                    Pragma: no-cache
                    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
                    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
                    P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi…
Headers           : {[Cache-Control, System.String[]], [Pragma, System.String[]], [Strict-Transport-Security, System.String[]], [X-Conte
                    nt-Type-Options, System.String[]]…}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
RawContentLength  : 503
RelationLink      : {}
```

[MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7#parameters) says:

> -SkipHttpErrorCheck
>
> ---
>
> This parameter causes the cmdlet to ignore HTTP error statuses and
> continue to process responses. The error responses are written to the
> pipeline just as if they were successful.

Comment: This is by far the easiest answer

Answer (score 5):

For me it only worked in a Pester context, when setting the streams Position to 0 before reading it.

```
        $statusCode = $null
        $responseBody = $null
        try {
            $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri "$($apiPrefix)$($operation)" -Headers $headers
            }
        catch [System.Net.WebException] {
            $statusCode = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
            $respStream = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
            $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($respStream)
            $reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
            $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd() | ConvertFrom-Json
        }
        $statusCode | Should Be $Expected
        $responseBody | Should Not Be $null
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are just after the response `StatusCode` and `Content` here is a novel way of solving this problem without lots of messy try/catch and manual reading of response streams:

```
# Place the trap within your chosen scope (e.g. function or script)
trap [Net.WebException] { continue; }

# Exceptions are no longer thrown here
$response = Invoke-WebRequest $endpoint

# Check if last command failed
if (!$?)
{   
    # $error[0] now contains the ErrorRecord of the last error (in this case from Invoke-WebRequest)
    # Note: $response should be null at this point

    # Due to the magic of Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand.WebCmdletWebResponseException
    # we can get the response body directly from the ErrorDetails field
    $body = $error[0].ErrorDetails.Message

    # For compatibility with $response.StatusCode lets cast to int    
    $statusCode = [int] $error[0].Exception.Response.StatusCode
}
```

As far as I can tell, the `ErrorRecord.ErrorDetails.Message` contains the exact equivalent to the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebResponseObject.Content` property that would get returned to you on a successful invocation of `Invoke-WebRequest`, just without the hassle of having to do all that `GetResponseStream()` jazz.

Comment: This solution also works with newest pwsh (checked with 7.2.5), while GetResponseStream() doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The textual response sent from the server is contained in the error variable at the following place:

```
$_.ErrorDetails.Message
```

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly as the OP intended; I had a similar case with wanting to see the body/headers of the SENT request, rather than the response.
The solution is `-SessionVariable VarNameHere` - You can then inspect this variable and see the exact content of the sent request.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the HTTPClient to get the raw response:

```
# initialise the HTTP client:
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Net.Http
$ignoreCerts = [System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler]::DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
$handler = [System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler]::new()
$handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = $ignoreCerts
$client = [System.Net.Http.HttpClient]::new($handler)

# define types for sending form-data via POST:
$kvPair = [System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[string,string]]
$kvList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[string,string]]]

$url = "https://api.mysite.com/the/endpoint"

# create the body for the web-call:
$form = $kvList::new()
$form.Add($kvPair::new('grant_type', 'password'))
$form.Add($kvPair::new('username', $user))
$form.Add($kvPair::new('password', $pass))
$content = [System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent]::new($form)

# send the POST command:
$result = $client.PostAsync($url, $content).Result
$response = $result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
write-host $response

# close-out:
$client.Dispose()
$handler.Dispose()
```