# powershell REST API issue with Meraki Dashboard API

Tags: rest, powershell

I'm having a problem with a specific REST api from meraki. I have been able to perform all the get operations with success, however the POST operations I am receiving a "308" error from the server. I'm trying to do the following:

Example request:

```
curl -L -H 'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key: <key>' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: 
application/json' --data-binary '{"name":"Miles Meraki", 
"email":"miles@meraki.com", "orgAccess":"none", "tags":[{"tag":"west", 
"access":"read-only"}]}' 
'https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations/1234/admins'
```

My Request:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri 
https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations/$global:MerakiOrg/admins/ -
Body $jbody -Headers $Global:MerakiHeader -ContentType 'application/json'
```

My $jbody value is the literal copied json from the example. I'm not familiar with this 308 code as a return code. Any guidance would be very helpful.

Comment: is `$jbody` a string or a powershell object?

Comment: can you provide the full return status? 308 is a permanent redirect and the new URL should be part of the response.

Comment: Having looked at the documentation, it reads like `v0` in the URL should perhaps be `v1` or whatever version of the API is currently released, that might explain the 308 redirect response. Either that or it's redirecting you to a login page perhaps because its rejecting your key? Per other comment, need the full error or to see where it's redirecting you.

Comment: 1.) when I run a get-member its showing as a System.String which is weird because I  i pipe that body into "convertto-json". If i run a convertfrom-json it properly puts it into a normal psobject format.

Comment: 2.)  @Micky-Balladelli when i output the exception, this is what i'm getting: 
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (308).

Comment: @MarkWragg From what i can tell form the documentation, the v0 is the appropriate version. I don't see a reference to any other version in the api docs. If it was rejecting my key then i would be getting a 404 error. This same key works for Get operations.

Comment: `ConvertTo-JSON` does create a string object, so that is correct. Its used to turn a PSObject in to a JSON formatted string. It does seem like the 308 response is likely HTTP 308 (the documentation explicitly says it returns HTTP codes). I know its shown above as you using https://, but is that actually what you're doing in your code? As that might be one thing that's being redirected (http -> https).

Comment: I would try using `Invoke-WebRequest` temporarily instead to see if you can capture the URL it seems to be trying to redirect you to. Should be in the `.Headers.Location` property of the response I believe.

Comment: @MarkWragg so you gave me the idea to put the api uri in the web browser and see if it redirects and it does. It redirects to: https://n158.meraki.com. So I updated the URI with that new redirected URL and i now got a different error a 400 return. This means there is something wrong or malformed with my request. I'm currently investigating with this new URI to see if i can get it working. I will update once i've tested.

Comment: I wonder if it's also worth trying adding -maximumredirection switch with the original URL and a high value. Maybe it needs to redirect more than the default max of 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out the issue, thanks to some of the responses I was able to get back on the trail and figure out. The first part of my problem was understanding what the 308 response error meant. After understanding that it was a redirect error I manually ran the rest command in the web browser to find out the redirect URL. I then used this URL as the URI prefix for my rest string. The second biggest issue I had in figuring out what was going wrong was that I wasn't getting enough information in the server response error. I found another stack overflow topic that showed me how to get the full json response
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986647/how-do-i-get-the-body-of-a-web-request-that-returned-400-bad-request-from-invoke)

After doing the streamreader method I got a better description of what my error was:

> Email miles@meraki.com is already registered with a Cisco Meraki Dashboard account. For s
> ecurity purposes, that user must verify his/her email address before administrator permis
> sions can be granted here.

So apparently the issue boiled down to me trying to create a test account on my dashboard with the same name as what was in the api example doc. I simply modified the email suffix with my own custom suffix and that resolved the issue and the rest command worked!

thanks to those who helped me point in the right direction.