# PowerShell Script RESTful API Binance URI structure

Tags: rest, api, powershell

I try to write a PowerShell Script and test it using https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order/test REST link but it doesn't work. I can't understand what should I use as message, what as body and what as header. It seems that here everything is clear and when I see a linux example I should have the same link in Output:
https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md
Could someone who understands REST Post method help me to figure out what should I change here.

My output is:
POST https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order/test?symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1515586306172&signature=LxHZUfC5MiTUfMPyEtgaVShlV1j4ITo3QxvtPAzPkwQ=

Many thanks in advance.

```
$apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$unixEpochStart = Get-Date -Date "01/01/1970"
$now = Get-Date
$timestamp = (New-TimeSpan -Start $unixEpochStart -End $now.ToUniversalTime()).TotalMilliseconds
$timestamp = ([math]::Round($timestamp, 0)).ToString()
$apimessage = "symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=$timestamp"
$apisecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Convert]::FromBase64String($apisecret)
$signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($apimessage))
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)

$uri = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order/test?$apimessage&signature=$signature"

$header = @{
        "X-MBX-APIKEY" = $apiKey
        }

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers $header -Verbose
```

Comment: Usually you have to GET first to authenticate, the REST should return your "X-MBX-APIKEY" data in the header. You should also wrap irm in a try/catch because you won't get the web server error responses without it.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986647/how-do-i-get-the-body-of-a-web-request-that-returned-400-bad-request-from-invoke/44000376#44000376) post out

Answer (score 1):

The issue is this line of code:

```
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)
```

Binance expects the HMAC SHA256 transmitted in hex form. Replace the above with this and the issue should be resolved.

```
$signature = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($signature).Replace('-', '').ToLower()
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is my working code. 
APIKey and Secret are from the example of the Binance API doc
https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#signed-endpoint-examples-for-post-apiv1order

Result of $Signature should be the same as in the Binance example: c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71

If you use your own APIKey and Secret it should be working

```
$APIKey = "vmPUZE6mv9SD5VNHk4HlWFsOr6aKE2zvsw0MuIgwCIPy6utIco14y7Ju91duEh8A"
$APISecret = "NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"

$TimeStamp = (Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s).replace(',', '').replace('.', '').SubString(0,13)

$QueryString = "symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559"

$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($APISecret)
$signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($QueryString))
$signature = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($signature).Replace('-', '').ToLower()

$uri = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?$QueryString&signature=$signature"

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("X-MBX-APIKEY",$APIKey)   

try {

    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Get
}

Catch {

    $streamReader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream())
    $ErrResp = $streamReader.ReadToEnd() | ConvertFrom-Json
    $streamReader.Close()
    $ErrResp
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, gives me a good start although the above throws error: -1101 Too many parameters; expected '3' and received '9'.

Answer (score 0):

below all the functions you need to request the Binance API.

Reference: https://blog.p-difm.com/interact-with-your-binance-account-using-the-api-and-powershell/

```
function Get-UnixTimeStamp{
        <#
            .SYNOPSIS
            Return the timestamp in millisecond of the Unix Epoch
    
            .DESCRIPTION
            Unix Epoch started the Thursday, January 1, 1970 12:00:00 AM. The function return the number of second from that time.
    
            .EXAMPLE
            Get-UnixTimeStamp
            
        #>
        param(
    
        )
    
        return $(Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s).replace(',', '').replace('.', '').SubString(0,13)
    }


function Get-BinanceAPISignature{
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
        Prepare the signature that will be sent with the API request

        .DESCRIPTION
        Endpoint requires sending a valid API-Key and signature

        .PARAMETER QueryString
        The queryString must contains the symobol, timestamp and a recvWindow

        .PARAMETER EndPoint
        The EndPoint you want to request

        .EXAMPLE
        $URI = Get-BinanceAPISignature -QueryString $QueryString -EndPoint "/api/v3/openOrders"
        
    #>
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$QueryString,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$EndPoint
    )
  
    $APISecret = "ASDHFASUHDFIOUSAHlUGLULUHALUHliuhalushduauauhIUH"

    $hmacsha     = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
    $hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($APISecret)
    $signature   = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($QueryString))
    $signature   = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($signature).Replace('-', '').ToLower()

    $URI = "https://api.binance.com$($EndPoint)?$QueryString&signature=$signature"
    
    return $URI
}



function Get-BinanceAPIHeader{
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
        Prepare the header that will be sent with the API request

        .DESCRIPTION
        The header include your APIKey

        .PARAMETER 
        #APIKey

        .EXAMPLE
        Get-BinanceAPIHeader
        
    #>
    param(
        
    )
  
    $APIKey = "HDAUSHF3989898hiuHGhuhI987898HiuahsduhaiusduhUIH"

    $Headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $Headers.Add("X-MBX-APIKEY",$APIKey)

    return $Headers
}



function Request-API{
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
        Run the CURL command with defined parameters

        .DESCRIPTION
        Call the API and error handling. Return the result of the request

        .PARAMETER Method
        Choose a method according to the EndPoint

        .PARAMETER URI
        This parameter needs to be obtained with Get-BinanceAPISignature

        .PARAMETER Headers
        This parameter needs to be obtained with Get-BinanceAPIHeaderx

        .EXAMPLE
        $ObjResults = Request-API -Method Get -URI $URI -Headers $Headers
    #>

    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateSet("POST","GET","DELETE")]$Method,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$URI,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Headers
    )

    try{
        $ArrayJsonResult = Curl $URI -Method $Method -Headers $Headers #-Verbose
        $ObjCustomResult = $ArrayJsonResult.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    }
    catch{
        $streamReader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream())
        $ErrResp = $streamReader.ReadToEnd() | ConvertFrom-Json
        $streamReader.Close()

        $LastError = $Error[0].ErrorDetails.Message | ConvertFrom-Json

        write-host "1: " $ErrResp -b Red
        write-host "2: " $LastError.code -b Red
        write-host "3: " $LastError.msg -b Red

        
        switch ($LastError.code){
            ("-1105") {write-host "TimeStamp issue"}
            ("-1003") {write-host "Too much request, IP Banned"; break}
            ("-2010") {write-host "Stop price would trigger immediately or Account has too many open stop loss and/or take profit orders on the symbol."}
            ("-1013") {write-host "The amount is not enough for this currency or not following the step size rule for the symbol."} 
            ("-1111") {write-host "Too many decimal check the precision required with Get-ExchangeInfo"}  
        }
    }
    
    return $ObjCustomResult
}
```

And here an example how to use it
Reference: https://blog.p-difm.com/new-order-with-api-binance-and-powershell/

```
function New-Order{
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
        Place an order to buy or sell crypto

        .PARAMETER Symbol
        The crypto you want to buy or sell

        .PARAMETER Side
        ValidateSet "BUY" or "SELL"

        .PARAMETER OrderType
        ValidateSet "OrderMarket" or "OrderLimit" or "OrderStopLimit"

        .PARAMETER Quantity
        Specifies the amount you want to spend (when buying) or receive (when selling)

        .PARAMETER FiatAmount
        specifies the amount you want to spend in USDT 

        .EXAMPLE
        New-Order -Symbol BTCUSDT -Side BUY -OrderType OrderMarket -FiatAmount 20 -Verbose

        .EXAMPLE
        New-Order -Symbol BTCUSDT -Side BUY -OrderType OrderLimit -FiatAmount 1000 -Price 33000    
        
        .EXAMPLE
        New-Order -Symbol BTCUSDT -Side BUY -OrderType OrderStopLimit -Quantity 0.002 -Price 33000 -StopPrice 36000

        .EXAMPLE
        New-Order -Symbol XRPUSDT -Side SELL -OrderType OrderLimit -Quantity 100 -Price 0.5 
        
        .EXAMPLE
        New-Order -Symbol XRPUSDT -Side SELL -OrderType OrderStopLimit -Quantity 100 -Price 0.55 -StopPrice 0.5
    #>

    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
        [string]$Symbol,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
        [ValidateSet("BUY", "SELL")]
        [string]$Side,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
        [ValidateSet("OrderMarket", "OrderLimit", "OrderStopLimit")]
        [string]$OrderType,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName = 'quantity')]
        [double]$Quantity,
    
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName = 'quantity2')] 
        [double]$FiatAmount
    )

    DynamicParam{
        $paramDictionary = New-Object -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary

        if ($OrderType -ne "OrderMarket"){
            # price param
            $attributes = New-Object -Type System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $attributes.Mandatory = $true
            $attributeCollection = New-Object -Type System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
            $attributeCollection.Add($attributes)

            $dynParam1 = New-Object -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter("Price", [double], $attributeCollection)
            $paramDictionary.Add("Price", $dynParam1)
        }
      
        if ($OrderType -eq "OrderStopLimit"){
            # StopPrice param
            $attributes2 = New-Object -Type System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $attributes2.Mandatory = $true
            $attributeCollection2 = New-Object -Type System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
            $attributeCollection2.Add($attributes2)

            $dynParam2 = New-Object -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter("StopPrice", [double], $attributeCollection2)
            $paramDictionary.Add("StopPrice", $dynParam2)
        }

        return $paramDictionary
    }

    BEGIN{
        # Check prerequisit
        try{
            Get-Command -Name Get-UnixTimeStamp -ErrorAction Stop | out-null
            Get-Command -name Get-BinanceAPISignature -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
            Get-Command -Name Get-BinanceAPIHeader -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
            Get-Command -Name Request-API -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
        }
        catch{
            Write-Host "Load Get-UnixTimeStamp, Get-BinanceAPISignature, Get-BinanceAPIHeader, Request-API  first prior to laod the current script" -b red
            Break
        }

        $TimeStamp = Get-UnixTimeStamp
        # retrieve value from dyn param
        if ($OrderType -ne "OrderMarket"){
            $Price     = $paramDictionary.values[0].value[0]
            $StopPrice = $paramDictionary.values[0].value[1]
        }

        switch($OrderType){
            "OrderMarket"{
                if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Quantity')){
                    $QueryString = "symbol=$Symbol&side=$Side&type=MARKET&quantity=$Quantity&timestamp=$TimeStamp&recvWindow=5000"
                }
                else{                                                                   
                    $QueryString = "symbol=$Symbol&side=$Side&type=MARKET&quoteOrderQty=$FiatAmount&timestamp=$TimeStamp&recvWindow=5000"
                }
            }
            
            "OrderLimit"{
                if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('FiatAmount')){
                    $CurrentPrice = Get-Price -Symbol $Symbol -Decimal 8
                    $Quantity = [math]::Round($FiatAmount / $CurrentPrice, 6)
                }
                $QueryString = "symbol=$Symbol&side=$Side&type=LIMIT&price=$Price&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=$Quantity&timestamp=$TimeStamp&recvWindow=5000"
            }

            "OrderStopLimit"{
                if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('FiatAmount')){
                    $CurrentPrice = Get-Price -Symbol $Symbol -Decimal 0
                    $Quantity = [math]::Round($FiatAmount / $CurrentPrice, 6)
                }
                $QueryString = "symbol=$Symbol&side=$Side&type=TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT&stopPrice=$StopPrice&price=$Price&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=$Quantity&timestamp=$TimeStamp&recvWindow=5000"
            }
        }
    }
    
    PROCESS{
        $URI = Get-BinanceAPISignature -QueryString $QueryString -EndPoint "/api/v3/order"
        $Headers = Get-BinanceAPIHeader
        $ObjResults = $null # need to do this?
        $ObjResults = Request-API -Method POST -URI $URI -Headers $Headers
    }

    END{
       return $ObjResults
    }
}
```