# Unable to get past the 400 Error

Tags: api, powershell, dropbox

Code to create a new user:

```
function New-DropBoxUser {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, Position=0)] 
        [string]$FullName
    )

    # Split name into username #
    $FirstName, $LastName = $FullName.split(' ')
    $UserName = ($FirstName[0]+$LastName).toLower()
    $email = "$UserName@mycomp.com"

    $Body = @{
        "new_members" = @(@{
            "member_email" = $email;
            "member_given_name" = $FirstName;                        
            "member_surname" = $LastName;
            "send_welcome_email" = "true";
            "role" = @{
                ".tag" = "member_only"
            }
        })
    }

    Write-Host ''
    Write-Host 'Creating DropBox User...' -ForegroundColor 'Yellow' -BackgroundColor 'Black'
    $AuthToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    $token = "Bearer $AuthToken" 

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod `
        -Method Post `
        -Uri "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/team/members/add" `
        -Headers @{ Authorization = $token } `
        -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" `
        -Body (ConvertTo-Json $Body)
}
```

Output:

> Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Anyone, please tell me the fix. I tried the Endpoint "team/members/list" to fetch user list using the same `$token` and it works.
I am totally new to Dropbox API so my code is borrowed from Google, while being good with PowerShell I tried to patch up using many different codes but none worked.

Comment: The error message may contain hints as to what you're doing wrong. I'd suggest you capture the error in a variable by adding `-ErrorVariable irmError` to the `Invoke-RestMethod` call and then hava look at `$irmError` afterwards

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I tried the -ErrorVariable but the variable has no data. Error not captured by this.

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod `
        -Method Post `
        -Uri "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/team/members/add" `
        -Headers @{ Authorization = $token } `
        -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" `
        -Body (ConvertTo-Json $Body) `
        -ErrorVariable $ero

        Write-Host $ero

Comment: Tried Try catch also to catch the exception,

Comment: try
    {
        Invoke-RestMethod `
            -Method Post `
            -Uri "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/team/members/add" `
            -Headers @{ Authorization = $token } `
            -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" `
            -Body (ConvertTo-Json $Body) `
            -ErrorVariable $ero `
            -ErrorAction Stop

            Write-Host $ero
            }
            catch
            {$ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            
            Write-Host $ErrorMessage}

Comment: Output: 
Creating DropBox User...
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: did you try this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986647/how-do-i-get-the-body-of-a-web-request-that-returned-400-bad-request-from-invoke

Comment: @techGaurdian, The Catch expression has given Output: "Error in call to API function "team/members/add": request body: new_members.send_welcome_email: u'true' is not a valid boolean" Cannot find anything wrong with my code. I tried replacing the "true" with 1 , 'true', $true. But all modifications fail. Can you suggest?

Comment: Update-----------

Comment: After commenting the following two lines the code works,

#"send_welcome_email"="true";
#"role" =  @{".tag" = "member_only"}

Please suggest a fix

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Create-new-Dropbox-user-using-Powershell/m-p/293978#M17897 ]

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails, [RTFM](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/teams#team-groups-members-add), whose parameters say:

```
{
    "new_members": [
        {
            "member_email": "tom.s@company.com",
            "member_given_name": "Tom",
            "member_surname": "Silverstone",
            "member_external_id": "company_id:342432",
            "send_welcome_email": true,
            "role": "member_only"
        }
    ],
    "force_async": false
}
```

Try removing `.tag` from the `role` definition and replace `"true"` with `$true`

```
$Body = @{
    "new_members" = @(@{
        "member_email" = $email
        "member_given_name" = $FirstName                        
        "member_surname" = $LastName
        "send_welcome_email" = $true
        "role" = "member_only"
    })
}
```

Comment: Edited in the `$true` for the native powershell boolean type.

Comment: Already tried the "send_welcome_email = $true but the code was failing, but after changing the role and removing the.tag it works.

Comment: I believe `$true` is the correct syntax. The generated JSON is `: true` in that case, whereas `"true"` yielded `: "true"`