# Azure Powershell automatic log-in to refresh Power BI

Tags: python, azure, powershell, automation, powerbi

I'm currently developing a script to automatically refresh one of my Power BI datasets using Power BI's REST API. This script is a .ps1 file, called from my Python code as you can see below. I followed step-by-step from [this](https://blogs.solidq.com/en/businessanalytics/how-to-refresh-power-bi-dataset-from-an-on-premise-power-shell-script/) tutorial, while my **refresh.ps1** file was developed from [this official MS source.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/powerbi-powershell/blob/master/manageRefresh.ps1) There were just some minor adaptations to make it run, so if anyone wants to test it, I suggest using the code I'm posting at the end of this question.

However, besides both codes work well and I they allow me to refresh my dataset, **every time they run I have to manually sign in in my Azure account through a prompted GUI**. This makes this script useless to automate tasks, such as in my case. See the picture of the GUI below:

[image]

I did some resource, but couldn't find any similar case, in which Python was also being used. About Powershell, I read about using ADAL, but couldn't really get what ADAL is.

So far, my Python script is:

```
import subprocess, sys

def powershell(file):

    p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", file], stdout=sys.stdout)
    p.communicate()

MS.powershell(r"'C:\blablabla\refresh.ps1'")
```

While my `refresh.ps1` file has the content shown below:

```
$groupID = "MY_GROUP_ID"
$datasetID = "MY_DATASET_ID"
$clientId = "MY_CLIENT_ID"

function GetAuthToken

{
       if(-not (Get-Module AzureRm.Profile)) {
         Import-Module AzureRm.Profile
       }

       $redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"

       $resourceAppIdURI = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"

       $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize";

       $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority

       $authResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resourceAppIdURI, $clientId, $redirectUri, "Auto")

       return $authResult
}

$token = GetAuthToken

$authHeader = @{
   'Content-Type'='application/json'
   'Authorization'=$token.CreateAuthorizationHeader()
}

$groupsPath = ""
if ($groupID -eq "me") {
    $groupsPath = "myorg"
} else {
    $groupsPath = "myorg/groups/$groupID"
}

$uri = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/$groupsPath/datasets/$datasetID/refreshes"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $authHeader -Method POST -Verbose
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to authenticate silently, you can use [UserCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.usercredential?view=azure-dotnet) class, and pass user name and password to AcquireToken method. Your GetAuthToken function should become something like this:

```
function GetAuthToken
{
       # Change these
       $username = "chuck@norris.com"
       $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "myP@ssw0rd" –asplaintext –force

       if(-not (Get-Module AzureRm.Profile)) {
         Import-Module AzureRm.Profile
       }

       $resourceAppIdURI = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"
       $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize";
       $credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username,$password
       $AADcredential = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential" -ArgumentList $credentials.UserName,$credentials.Password
       $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority

       $authResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resourceAppIdURI,$clientId,$AADcredential)

       return $authResult
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but I'm getting an error `Invoke-RestMethod`: 400 (bad request)

Comment: This code is outside of the function. You should check your code. Are you constructing correct URL? The initialization of `$groupsPath` seams rotten to me.

Comment: I'm getting the entire function from the link I mentioned above (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/powerbi-powershell/blob/master/manageRefresh.ps1)

Comment: Since my original code wasn't returning this mistake, I believe it does have something to do with the authorization method. Maybe the `$authHeader` wasn't expecting the patterns of user and password, but instead `$groupID`, `$datasetID` and `clientId`, that weren't used in the function mentined in your answer...

Comment: Nope, I just copy/pasted your code, replaced the function with my version, set `$groupID`, `$datasetID` and `$clientId` with values from my environment, and successfully refreshed the dataset.

Comment: Just checked it and you are right! Both codes aren't working... So there is probably something wrong with the POST request I'm doing, right? Or could this be some BI limitation (such as limit of refreshes per day)?

Comment: There is a limit of 8 refreshes per 24h. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986647/how-do-i-get-the-body-of-a-web-request-that-returned-400-bad-request-from-invoke) question and see the response text. It should hint you why you get 400.

Comment: Okay, it's done! The problem was, indeed the reaching of the refresh limit! Thank you very much for your pacience and all the help!